# installation works with Webbrowser but not with webview2

Tags: webview2

Please excuse my english

I have software developed with VB.NET that uses WEBBROWSER.

With the end of internet explorer I am moving to Webview2. The adaptation went well but I encounter a problem for the creation of the installation file (by inosetup). The file that I have been using for several years does not work, after installation, at launch, nothing happens.

I added :

```
Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll
Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Winforms.dll
Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WPF.dll
```

After installation and launch, the application is visible in the task manager but not visible.

Passing through the .exe of BIN/RELEASE the application works normally.

I noticed that in my application folder in 'program files' I am missing the 'runtimes' and '`My_Application.exe.WebView2`' folders

'Runtimes' is installed fine on my PCs (1 in W7 and 1 in W10) and it happens on the 2 different apps I just adapted from Webbrowser to Webwiew2

Thank you for your precious help because I'm going crazy !

Answer (score 0):

For .NET apps using WebView2, in addition to shipping

- `Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll`
- `Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Winforms.dll`
- `Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WPF.dll`

You'll also need to ship

- `WebView2Loader.dll`

The `WebView2Loader.dll` is a native DLL so you'll need to ship it in the various CPU architectures that your .NET apps supports and you'll need to place the files on disk in the following manner:

```
\<myApp>
    \Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll
    \Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Winforms.dll
    \Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WPF.dll
    \runtimes
        \win-arm64\native\WebView2Loader.dll (arm64)
        \win-x64\native\WebView2Loader.dll (x64)
        \win-x86\native\WebView2Loader.dll (x86)
```

See the [Files to ship with your app document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#files-to-ship-with-the-app) and the rest of that document for more information.

Additionally, you must be sure to specify your user data folder (UDF) as described in the [Manage user data folders documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/user-data-folder?tabs=win32). The UDF is where WebView2 stores all state including HTTP cache, cookies, localStorage, and so on. By default the UDF is placed in a path `[exe name].WebView2` next to the exe. However, when installed in `Program Files`, the application is unlikely to have permission to create the UDF in that folder. You should specify a UDF location as described in the documentation.